# How to add function in a block,call this function in template

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, plugin

In the layout file `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" after="logo" template="cart/minicart.phtml">
```

I would like to add a new method to block `Sidebar.php`.

Then call in the template and the `minicart.phtml`.

I found in `app/code/Magento/Customer/etc/frontend/di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar">
    <plugin name="customer_cart" type="Magento\Customer\Model\Cart\ConfigPlugin" />
</type>
```

so I cant't use preference for `Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar` to add function in `Sidebar.php`.

Preference didn't work:  `app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/di.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" type="Vendor\Modulename\Block\Cart\Sidebar" />
</config>
```

block file `Vendor\Modulename\Block\Cart\Sidebar`

```
class Sidebar extends \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar
{
    protected $_logger;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image $imageHelper,
        \Magento\Customer\CustomerData\JsLayoutDataProviderPoolInterface $jsLayoutDataProvider,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data
    ){
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context, $customerSession, $checkoutSession, $imageHelper, $jsLayoutDataProvider, $data);
    }

    public function getCheckoutUrl()
    {
        $this->_logger->addDebug("AAAAAAAAAAA");
        return parent::getCheckoutUrl(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
    }
}
```

In `var/log/debug.log`, there is nothing to print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento2.1 fix plugin and preference problem

Comment: Which problem, and how is it related to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You have to first override block for add new function in sidebar.php file.

You cant use plugin method for add new function in block file.
You can use plugin method to overrider already defined public function in file.

You must have to overrider sidebar.php file and add new function inside sidebar.php file after adding function you can call those function inside your template file.

under

```
Vendor/Modulename/etc/di.xml
```

file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" type="Vendor/Modulename/Block/Cart/Sidebar" />

</config>
```

Inside sidebar.php file,

**Vendor/Modulename/Block/Cart/Sidebar.php**

you can define your new function.

Comment: I edited the question, preference didn't work for me

Comment: you have to remove var folder and remove plugin declaration from xml

Comment: I remove the var folder and plugin declaration is core module,like app/code/Magento/Customer/etc/frontend/di.xml  . <plugin name="customer_cart" type="\Magento\Customer\Model\Cart\ConfigPlugin" />. You can't remove from core module